# Getting a variable from a Server script to a Client script

Tags: javascript, node.js, autodesk-forge

Here's the current issue i'm struggling with. I'm on a webapp project, in which I have 2 scripts :

- A script called `start.js` in which I initialize the server and initialize a variable, `token`. This script is ran when I start the webapp.
- A script called `viewer.js` which initialize a viewer. That viewer requires the previous `token` to work.

I can't generate the token from the client side, because it requires NodeJS, and as far as I understood NodeJS doesn't work on Client side.

I've tried to use global variables, global methods, or HTTP requests, but none of these methods seems to work so far. **Any tip on how to do it ?**

Here is what I tried:

```
// start.js
const ForgeSDK = require('forge-apis');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

/**
 * Token generation
 */

oAuth2TwoLegged.authenticate().then(function(credentials){
    setToken(credentials.access_token)
}, function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
function setToken(newToken) {
    console.log("Definition du nouveau token")
    token = newToken;
    console.log(token)
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html')); 
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Token provider listening on port 3000')
});
```

```
// viewer.js
var token = '';
/**
 * Viewer initialization
 */
```

Comment: Couldn't you create a service in your API so that the client can call the service, back-end generates the token and returns it to the client.  Then the client can use it in subsequent request?

Comment: @ChrisAdams that's the idea, but I was not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback to your config options to obtain the token (usually via ajax) to requests:

```
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {
        //
        // TODO: Replace static access token string below with call to fetch new token from your backend
        // Both values are provided by Forge's Authentication (OAuth) API.
        //
        // Example Forge's Authentication (OAuth) API return value:
        // {
        //    "access_token": "<YOUR_APPLICATION_TOKEN>",
        //    "token_type": "Bearer",
        //    "expires_in": 86400
        // }
        //
        var accessToken = '<YOUR_APPLICATION_TOKEN>';
        var expireTimeSeconds = 86400;
        onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
    }
}

 Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
  ...
```

See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-viewer/) for details.

And see [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-navigation.sample/blob/master/server/token.js#L26) and [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-navigation.sample/blob/master/server/forge.js#L41) to create an endpoint to generate access tokens in your Node backend.